# Jenkins maven splits version range

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

## The problem

Maven interprets:

```
versions:update-parent -N -DallowSnapshots=true -DparentVersion=[1.8.0,1.9.0)
```

as:

```
versions:update-parent -N -DallowSnapshots=true '-DparentVersion=[1.8.0' '1.9.0)'
```

I'm trying to run Maven in Jenkinsfile pipeline like so (line breaks added for readability, this is all on one line):

```
sh "mvn release:clean release:prepare -X 
-DcheckModificationExcludeList=pom.xml,pom.xml.versionsBackup 
-Dresume=false 
-DpreparationGoals=\'clean install -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true' 
-Darguments=\'-Dbuild.phase.beforeDeploy -DskipTests=true\' 
-DcompletionGoals=\'versions:update-parent -N -DallowSnapshots=true -DparentVersion=[1.8.0,1.9.0)\' 
-DtagNameFormat=@{project.groupId}-@{project.artifactId}-@{project.version}"
```

When Maven starts executing the completion goals section it splits the version range, treats it as 2 separate parameters and exits with an error. Relevant log fragments:

```
[INFO] Executing goals 'versions:update-parent -N -DallowSnapshots=true -DparentVersion=[1.8.0,1.9.0)'...
[DEBUG] Using ${maven.home} of: '/home/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/mvn-3.2.5'.
[DEBUG] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/jenkins/workspace/ife-jen-maven-runner_master-6CIUKZ3STQA5HR4E2RYGZ5GBNFZPFT7UYLMWJ5EMFIBJ6ATW7RUA/appdir && /home/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/mvn-3.2.5/bin/mvn -X -D maven.repo.local=/home/jenkins/.m2/repository -s /tmp/release-settings1714400534004224741.xml -D skipTests=true -D build.phase.beforeDeploy=true -P nexus versions:update-parent -N -DallowSnapshots=true '-DparentVersion=[1.8.0' '1.9.0)'

[INFO] [DEBUG] === REACTOR BUILD PLAN ================================================
[INFO] [DEBUG] Project: my-project:pom:6.4.123-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] [DEBUG] Tasks:   [versions:update-parent, 1.9.0)]

INFO] [ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "1.9.0)". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase...

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project grin-colis: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1' -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project grin-colis: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
```

Have you ever encountered a similar problem? How did you deal with it?

## Setup

The build is running on a linux Docker slave (the container is not managed by Jenkins).

## Versions

- Jenkins 2.46.1
- Pipeline 2.5
- Maven Integration plugin 2.16
- Container JDK OpenJDK 1.8.0_121
- Job JDK Oracle JDK 6u45 (java 6 required by project, using the install automatically option and declared in Jenkinsfile tools section)
- Maven 3.2.5
- Maven versions plugin 2.4 (declared in pom)

Comment: The single quote symbol is used not collect, may be  `-DparentVersion='[1.8.0 1.9.0)'`

Comment: The first thing i don't understand is why are you using versions-maven-plugin if you use maven-release-plugin? Why are you redefining `preparationGoals` and `completionGoals`? And what is need to update a parent during the release process ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm not the author of the release process itself. I'm only supposed to port it to Jenkins pipeline, preferably altering it as little as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the culprit was the newest version (2.5.3) of maven-release-plugin. I have not yet tested whether newer versions (2.3.x, 2.4.x) would work.

Running this configuration in the project helped:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-gitexe</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to put the arguments into (escaped) quotes:

```
sh "mvn release:clean release:prepare -X 
-DcheckModificationExcludeList=pom.xml,pom.xml.versionsBackup 
-Dresume=false 
-DpreparationGoals=\'clean install -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true' 
-Darguments=\'-Dbuild.phase.beforeDeploy -DskipTests=true\' 
-DcompletionGoals=\'versions:update-parent -N -DallowSnapshots=true -DparentVersion=\"[1.8.0,1.9.0)\"\' 
-DtagNameFormat=@{project.groupId}-@{project.artifactId}-@{project.version}"
```

Comment: After using this format `-DcompletionGoals='versions:update-parent -N -DallowSnapshots=true -DparentVersion=\"[1.8.0,1.9.0)\"'` The result is `[INFO] Executing goals 'versions:update-parent -N -DallowSnapshots=true -DparentVersion="[1.8.0,1.9.0)'... Error translating Commandline.` If I replace the escaped double quotes with escaped single quotes I get a shell error `Syntax error: ")" unexpected`